# When to use xib and when to use ContainerView?

Tags: swift, xcode, xib, uicontainerview

I want to know when to use `xib` and when to use `UIContainerView`?

I didn't find any article related to this topic in the web. What are the differences and what are the usage of each of them?

Comment: There s no real answer to this. But in short may be this holds: `•` Use XIB if you are not using storyboards anywhere. `•` ContainerViews works well with storyboards, outside of it its just a plain view. (In storyboard you can drag & drop to embed another controller)

Comment: If you want to reuse the same view then you should use xib otherwise container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first talk definitions:

- A XIB file is a graphical representation of a screen/view.
- A UIContainerView is exactly what it says, it's a view that will contain child view controllers.

So based on that it is clear that they will not be used in the same way.
A XIB file is a base file you create in Xcode, link to a UIViewController and in which you can drag and drop elements to design your screens.

UIViewContainer is one of those draggable elements and is simply meant to be a reserved space in your xib (or storyboard if you use that instead) in which you can easily "embed" another UIViewController.

Do you sometimes add a child UIViewController to your main UIViewController? You'd do something like this in code:

- Instantiate second controller
- Add second controller's view as subview in main controller
- Add second controller as child of main controller
- Create constraints so that view shows exactly where intended

Well the UIContainerView is here to do exactly this, only now you don't have to do it in code, you can drag a UIContainerView in you XIB/Storyboard and link the second controller there directly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.xib` design file for a standalone `View` (like `custom datePickerView`, `CustomAlertView`, `customViews` etc). Use can use this `class` where every you want.

But `ContainerView`, you can design with a `UIViewController` on `storyboard` and its automatically generate its own view for you.

This is embedded with a single `ViewController`.

Comment: A xib defines a standalone `UIView`, not a `UIViewController`. It can be used to initialize the view of a controller but using storyboards for controllers is always better.